# Carrierwave extension_white_list is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, carrierwave

I am trying to upload a file using carrierwave gem in rails. I want to allow users to only upload files. So, I have used the extension_white_list method of uploader as shown below. But then also it allows users to upload images.I am allowing the user to choose multiple files and my controller code is as below.

Can you please point me where I am wrong?

thanks in advance.

MyUploader.rb

```
def extension_white_list
   %w(pdf doc htm html docx)
end
```

MyController.rb

```
def create
   @store_id = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current.myshopify_domain 
   @store = Shop.find_by_shopify_domain(@store_id)
   # @uuid=@store.uuid
   @attachment=params[:swatch][:attachment] 

   @attachment_json=[]
   @attachment.each do |aa|
     @swatch = Swatch.new(:store_id => @store.uuid,:attachment => aa)
     @swatch.save
     @attachment_json.push({ id: @swatch.id, url: @swatch.attachment.url})
   end
   render json: @attachment_json
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is called extension_white_list or extension_whitelist. It depends on your gem version